# How to display an error page in HTML project?

Tags: html

how to display the error page in html project. my project is full of html code like index.html ,about.html and contact.html , If I enter the wrong URL. I want to show error error.

example: http://stackoverflow.com is correct URL.

https://stackoverflow.com/dsffdsfdsf  is wrong URL. I want to show error page for that.

Comment: You'll need a 404 page, but what technology are you using? This is a good start tho - http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472591

Comment: only am using html coding. technology???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very complicated. You need to know all about C#, C++, C, HTML, PHP, jQuery and Javascript.

*Nope, just a joke.* You can do it simply by following these steps :

1. Create a file *at the root of your HTML project*, name it as ".htaccess", if it doesn't exist
2. Add this code snippet to your `.htaccess` :

   ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
3. Create a file called "404.html" at the root of your HTML project. Make whatever you want in that file.
4. Host the project or just run it locally.
5. Now you're completed!

For more information check this out : [Tutorial](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/)

Comment: 404 page is works good. But 403 page is not working i gave link like this in htaccess  ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/ss/404.html
          ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/ss/403.html